# Is Jetty incompatible with Spring?

Tags: spring, gwt, maven, jetty, smartgwt

I'm still on that huge GWT+smartGWT+Selenium+Maven project. I just learned that there is no tomcat on the continuous integration server.
So I found that the simpler way to use Selenium on the integration server was :

*Deploy the application with an embded container (jetty) and then unit test it with Selenium RC.*

There is only one problem left. When I try launching jetty with that webapp (with jetty:run-war or jetty:run) it gives me looooaaads of errors and I think it comes from Spring.
Here is the link of the pastebin of my errors : http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=4Qg4TXBE
When I try to access the jetty server with my browser it says : "Service unavalaible"

My build phase is :
*- Unit tests on the server side

- Building war

- Starting Jetty and deploy war

- Starting Selenium server and unit testing the client side

- Closing Selenium server

- Closing Jetty container

- Sending the surefire reports of my tests to Sonar*

So here is my question : **What should I do to launch Jetty properly ?**
Would cargo-maven-plugin solve that problem ?
Is there a simple way to get Jetty working with Spring ?

Thanks again for your answers, you guys help me a lot ^^
(Sorry for my bad english, still not good at that)

Comment: AFAIK, Your application seems to use JNDI names to access datasources: `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name 'agepro-ds'`. But you didn't register this datasource in your servlet container. Please show your pom.xml.

Comment: Here you go : http://pastebin.com/66QikQzj    
Thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at this article to declare your JNDI datasource called 'agepro-ds': http://umanga.wordpress.com/2008/11/07/maven-jetty-plugin-jndi-jdbcdbcp-configuration/

Comment: Thanks a lot. i'll give this a try and will accept this as an answer to my problem. Thanks a lot for helping me.

Comment: Jetty is an embeded container, where am I supposed to declare those things ? (My configuration of tomcat declares the JDNI sources so I can copy paste that declaration)

Comment: According to the link I gave, it is in `WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml`

Comment: Yeah I saw that. But where in the project am I supposed to declare that ? In my test classpath ? In the root of the project ? 
I mean : ?/WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml what should I replace th interrogation mark with ?

Comment: Search for the file called `web.xml` in your project. The `jetty-env.xml` file must be placed in the same location.

Comment: I'll toss in that there is a jetty-spring module that helps configure jetty with spring xml syntax as well.

Comment: In fact it was simple to declare the datasource once you know where to place the jetty-env.xml.